# What gambling type dapps have been created for EOS?

Tags: dapp, gambling

What are some gambling dapps that are created with EOS? Are there any gambling dapps that are not website centralized as in I can play the dapp with just a simple html/js file interacting with the EOS blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a complete list of eos dApp on [DappRadar](https://dappradar.com/eos-dapps). There are several categories including gambling.